# How to exclude multiple modules from a run cts?

Tags: android, cts

I try to launch a complete run cts test except the one i already Know are false.
When i have only one wrong, run cts --exclude-filter work fine but won't work with multiple arguments... Is there an easy way to exclude multiple modules from a run cts without using plan or subplan? Or an easy way to create a plan to pass all tests except few modules?
Thx